# FontResolver to add **Myriad Pro** Font in PDFsharp 1.32

Tags: c#, fonts, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015, pdfsharp

I am looking to add the Font(Myriad Pro) to the PDF Invoice generated via PDFsharp, but unable to do so.

What I have tried so far is:

- `EZFontResolver.cs` class-file provided by a developer on the [following **link**](http://developer.th-soft.com/developer/ezfontresolver-a-generic-font-resolver-for-pdfsharp-and-migradoc/)
  (And posted my comment-problem there as well, but did not recieve any response.)
  It gives me an exception **{“Must not change font resolver after is was once used.”}** when the following code line executes:
  `GlobalFontSettings.FontResolver = fontResolver;`
- also tried Beta Version `1.50.xx`

Comment: The error indicates that you have already set `GlobalFontSettings.FontResolver` in your code ***and*** rendered a PDF. Once you have done this, PDFSharp does not allow you to change the value of `GlobalFontSettings.FontResolver`  again.

Comment: :-) It is at the very first line of the program after creating an object of class **PdfDocument()**

Comment: So try setting the `FontResolver` ***before*** referring to any other PdfSharp functionality.

Comment: Thank you@spender ....! Now, i am using pdfSharp 1.32 , and EZFontResolver is inherited from IFontResolver which the Compiler is unable to find. Any suggestion what to do

Comment: I'm ready to use 1.50 then (any from the beta, beta2, beta3) but i also want to use the Pen Class with rectangles - which is not allowed to add in the rectangle. (Any other way to use pen with this latest version)

Comment: @spender I can remove my answer if you reply (so you get the reputation). To Malik Asif: I don't understand the point with Pen and Rectangle. Not enough information in the original question, too much information in comments. Difficult to follow.

Comment: @PDFsharpTeam It sounds far more official from you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font resolver is a global setting (as user "spender" pointed out in their comments). This global settings is shared by all instances of PdfDocument() and it can be set only once.

The font resolver is a new feature of PDFsharp 1.50 (there was a breaking change with beta 2, so samples for beta 1 may no longer work with the current beta 3). For PDFsharp 1.32 a different approach must be used.

When using the WPF build of PDFsharp 1.32, you will find a sample that shows the usage of private fonts in the samples folder that comes with the source package of PDFsharp (sample folder is PrivateFonts).

Comment: Can you please share the approach to a better one. It'll be better for me if i use the Stable version as i am working on a live Product (Never mind, i am a learner as well as weaker in Interface concepts and documentation is a bit confusing on this [**LINK**](http://developer.th-soft.com/developer/using-private-fonts-with-pdfsharp-1-50-beta-or-migradoc/) ) Please help me in clarifying the ways pdfsharp uses to resolve the Font Issues

Comment: I updated my answer with information on PDFsharp 1.32 (WPF build). IMHO PDFsharp 1.50 beta 3 is much better than version 1.32.

Comment: Thank you PDF-Sharp Team. I am using 1.50 beta-3b and it is a great start. Using **DemoFontResolver.cs** provided at [this **Link**](http://developer.th-soft.com/developer/using-private-fonts-with-pdfsharp-1-50-beta-or-migradoc/)